# Cannot click on items in listview in fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-studio, android-listview

i have project with Navigation Drawer Activity... there are many fragments with ListView. Items in ListView has (TextView, CheckBox, TextView, ImageView)...

I want to do some action if i click on whole item(TextView, CheckBox, TextView, ImageView) and another action if i click on CheckBox.

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.kubitas.app" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Jidlo"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_jidlo" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks,
                   Kontakt.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
                   Pizzy.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
                   Uvod.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
                   Ciabatta.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
                   Salaty.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
                   Brambory.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
                   Dezerty.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
                   Napoje.OnFragmentInteractionListener
                   {

    /**
     * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
     */
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

    /**
     * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
     */
    private CharSequence mTitle;

   private ArrayList<JidloClass> ObjednavkaList = new ArrayList<JidloClass>();
   private CheckBox objednat;
   private TextView id;
   private TextView nazev;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
    }


    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new Uvod();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new Pizzy();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new Ciabatta();
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new Salaty();
                break;
            case 4:
                fragment = new Brambory();
                break;
            case 5:
                fragment = new Dezerty();
                break;
            case 6:
                fragment = new Napoje();
                break;
            case 7:
                fragment = new Kontakt();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                .commit();
    }

    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri){
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Toast.makeText(this, "something" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    public void onFragmentInteraction(String id){
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Toast.makeText(this, "something" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }



    public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
        switch (number) {
            case 0:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section0);
                break;
            case 1:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
                break;
            case 2:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
                break;
            case 3:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
                break;
            case 4:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section4);
                break;
            case 5:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section5);
                break;
            case 6:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section6);
                break;
            case 7:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section7);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
    }

     public void onCheckBoxClicked(View view){
       // There i cant hold which CheckBox been clicked -> i want to add whole object into list ->
         // but i dont know if that checkbox was checked on 1. or 3. row
     }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
            // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
            // decide what to show in the action bar.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            restoreActionBar();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

One fragment(xml is default if creating Fragment(List)):

```
 public class Pizzy extends Fragment implements AbsListView.OnItemClickListener {


private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

/**
 * The fragment's ListView/GridView.
 */
private ListView mListView;

/**
 * The Adapter which will be used to populate the ListView/GridView with
 * Views.
 */
private ListAdapter mAdapter;


private LayoutInflater layoutx;


List<JidloClass> listNew = new ArrayList<JidloClass>();

public static Pizzy newInstance() {
    Pizzy fragment = new Pizzy();
    return fragment;
}

/**
 * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
 * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
 */
public Pizzy() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    JidloClass p0 = new JidloClass(0, true, "Sunkova","", R.mipmap.logo);
    JidloClass p1 = new JidloClass(1, true, "Sunkova","", R.mipmap.logo);
    JidloClass p2 = new JidloClass(2, false, "Sunkova","", R.mipmap.logo);

    listNew = new Vector<JidloClass>();
    listNew.add(p0);
    listNew.add(p1);
    listNew.add(p2);


    layoutx = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pizza, container, false);


    mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(),
            R.layout.activity_jidlo, R.id.ListJidlo, listNew);



    // Set the adapter
    mListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    ((AdapterView<ListAdapter>) mListView).setAdapter(mAdapter);

    // Set OnItemClickListener so we can be notified on item clicks
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    return view;
}


@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(1);
    try {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}




@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    if (null != mListener) {
        // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
        // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(listNew.get(position).getNazev());
    }
}

/**
 * The default content for this Fragment has a TextView that is shown when
 * the list is empty. If you would like to change the text, call this method
 * to supply the text it should use.
 */
public void setEmptyText(CharSequence emptyText) {
    View emptyView = mListView.getEmptyView();

    if (emptyView instanceof TextView) {
        ((TextView) emptyView).setText(emptyText);
    }
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p/>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    public void onFragmentInteraction(String id);
}


private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<JidloClass>
{
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource,
                         int textViewResourceId, List<JidloClass> objects)
    {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        ViewHolder holder = null;
        TextView title = null;
        TextView id = null;
        CheckBox objednat = null;
        ImageView i11=null;
        JidloClass rowData = getItem(position);
        if(null == convertView)
        {
            convertView = layoutx.inflate(R.layout.activity_jidlo, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        i11=holder.getImage();
        i11.setImageResource(listNew.get(rowData.getId()).getObrazek());
        title = holder.gettitle();
        title.setText(listNew.get(rowData.getId()).getNazev());
        id = holder.getID();
        id.setText(Integer.toString(listNew.get(rowData.getId()).getId())+".");
        objednat = holder.getObjednat();
        objednat.setChecked(listNew.get(rowData.getId()).getObjednat());


        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder
    {
        private View mRow;
        private TextView title = null;
        private TextView id = null;
        private ImageView i11=null;
        private CheckBox objednat = null;

        public ViewHolder(View row)
        {
            mRow = row;
        }
        public TextView gettitle()
        {
            if(null == title)
            {
                title = (TextView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.txtNazev);
            }
            return title;
        }
        public TextView getID()
        {
            if(null == id)
            {
                id = (TextView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.txtID);
            }
            return id;
        }
        public ImageView getImage()
        {
            if(null == i11)
            {
                i11 = (ImageView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.imgJidlo);
            }
            return i11;
        }
        public CheckBox getObjednat()
        {
            if(null == objednat)
            {
                objednat = (CheckBox) mRow.findViewById(R.id.chbObjednat);
            }
            return objednat;
        }
    }
}


}
```

Activity of items:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:clickable="true"
    tools:context="com.example.kubitas.pizzamotolapp.Jidlo"
    android:id="@+id/ListJidlo">

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/chbObjednat"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtID"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txtID"
        android:onClick="onCheckBoxClicked"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/txtNazev"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/chbObjednat"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/chbObjednat" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imgJidlo"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="1."
        android:id="@+id/txtID"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/chbObjednat"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have these problems: 
  I cant click on item in ListView... (If i click on item there isnt any reaction)
  I dont know if i can do 2 others actions (one if click on whole item, one if i click on CheckBox)

Please can you help me? Im trying this about 5hours and nothing.

Many thanks and sorry for much code.

Comment: I think your mListner is null try to insert any log message or toast inside `onItemClick` outside this ` if (null != mListener) ` put any toast or log message .

Comment: Nothing.. whats wrong with listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

Don't use

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

set OnClickListener in your ArrayAdapter

inside getView

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      // put your code here                     
   }
});
```

Hope this help !

Comment: thanks... but it works for both actions... do you know how to separe this 2 actions? 2 methods (1. for click on checkbox and 2. for click on whole item )

Comment: the ClickListener above is for the whole ListItem, if you want to add another ClickListener to Checkbox in your ListItem. Just call checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Checkbox on clicked");
                        }
                    }); in the getView too.